# How to choose a good namespace name? (Linguistically)

Tags: c#, .net, namespace

English in not my native language, therefore it is a little more difficult to pick a good name for a namespace. One example to make you see my problem a bit better:

We have a set of classes that have to do with the way a company is organized (we can create organizational charts with it). Currently the namespace is `CFW.CoreSystem.Organizational`. Is this a good name?

What is **linguistically** the best way to name a namespace? (`CFW.CoreSystem.Configuration` is better than `CFW.CoreSystem.Configurables`).

<sub>[Moved it from [StackOverflow]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8269002/how-to-choose-a-good-namespace-name-linguistically)</sub>

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> The name chosen for a namespace should indicate the functionality made
> available by types in the namespace. For example, the
> System.Net.Sockets namespace contains types that enable developers to
> use sockets to communicate over networks.

The general format for a namespace name is as follows:

```
<Company>.(<Product>|<Technology>)[.<Feature>][.<Subnamespace>]
```

For example, Microsoft.WindowsMobile.DirectX.

Do use Pascal casing, and separate namespace components with periods (for example, Microsoft.Office.PowerPoint). If your brand employs nontraditional casing, you should follow the casing defined by your brand, even if it deviates from normal namespace casing.

Consider using plural namespace names where appropriate. For example, use System.Collections instead of System.Collection. Brand names and acronyms are exceptions to this rule, however. For example, use System.IO instead of System.IOs.

Do not use the same name for a namespace and a type in that namespace. For example, do not use Debug for a namespace name and also provide a class named Debug in the same namespace. Several compilers require such types to be fully qualified.

There are lots of Do or Do'not detail on MSDN regarding Naming of namespace, Assemblies etc.
Check this out for [Namespaces](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229026.aspx)

`CFW.CoreSystem.Configuration` is better.

> The Namespace CFW.CoreSystem.Organizational is pretty good but
> CFW.CoreSystem.Organization is much better to write.

Comment: I know the guidelines... but as a non native English speaker I was wondering why `Configuration` is better than `Configurable`?

Comment: It's more common to use nouns in namespaces. I see you're Dutch, so maybe it's more understandable when I say it in Dutch: het is gebruikelijk om zelfstandige naamwoorden te gebruiken in namespaces. In jouw geval zou Configurables vertalen naar 'configureerbaarheden' en Configuration naar 'configuratie'. Waarbij de tweede optie toch iets beter klinkt.

Comment: @kees I'd say `Configuration` is better because the namespace contains functionality regarding the application Configuration - it could also contain relevant utilities and the like. `Configurables` tells me that everything within that namespace is something that is configurable. Which might not be the case.

Comment: @KeesC.Bakker I'm late, but the reason a namespace called `Configuration` is better than `Configurable` is that *nouns*, rather than *adjectives*, should be used to name namespaces. For example `Configuration` is a noun. Adjectives are more appropriate for interfaces (e.g. `IConfigurable`, `ISerializable`, etc).